# Scroll Spy won't work - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I can't for the life of me firgure out why I can't get my scroll spy to work. Here is the code below.  Is there anything that jumps out at someone where I went wrong?  I read a number of these posts and couldn't figure my own out.  This is the first time going through the scroll spy so I am mostly copying code for W3schools or bootply.  I am using the ID #nav for all of calls after i set the spy target.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<body class="body" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav">
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">#HappilyEverManca</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#Section1">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Section2">About Us</a></li>          
              <li><a href="#Section3">Location</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Section4">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container -->
    </div><!--/.navbar -->
```

With the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {




    /* affix the navbar after scroll below header */
    $('#nav').affix({
          offset: {
            top: $('header').height()-$('#nav').height()
          }
    }); 

    /* highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs */
    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#nav' })



    /* smooth scrolling for nav sections */
    $('#nav .navbar-nav li>a').click(function(){
      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      var posi = $(link).offset().top;
      $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:posi},700);
    });


});
```

Comment: Is `$('#nav').scrollspy()` supposed to be there? I don't see that in the Bootstrap docs example. Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: actually probably not. I added that at some point while I was trying different things to get it to work.  I will remove it.

Comment: _Doesn't work_ does not describe the issue you're having, provide details about what you're trying to accomplish and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: Sure,  A scroll spy would keep the navbar present at the top of screen as you scroll down to the different sections in the html.  My navbar disappears and stays fixed at the very top of the page and doesn't follow you downwards as you scroll.  Does that help clarify? if not please let me know and I will try to expand upon that

Comment: "My navbar disappears and stays fixed at the very top".. if it disappears, it doesn't stay fixed. Use `navbar-fixed-top` instead of the static navbar.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that did not produce a different result